# MDX - filter empty outside of selected range

Tags: filter, ssas, mdx, date-range

Cube is populated with data divided into time dimension ( period ) which represents a month.
 
Following query: 
`select non empty {[Measures].[a], [Measures].[b], [Measures].[c]} on columns, 
{[Period].[Period].ALLMEMEMBERS} on rows 
from MyCube`
returns:
`+--------+----+---+--------+
| Period | a  | b |   c    |
+--------+----+---+--------+
|      2 |  3 | 2 | (null) |
|      3 |  5 | 3 | 1      |
|      5 | 23 | 2 | 2      |
+--------+----+---+--------+`

Removing non empty 
`select {[Measures].[a], [Measures].[b], [Measures].[c]} on columns, 
{[Period].[Period].ALLMEMEMBERS} on rows 
from MyCube`
Renders:
`+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Period |   a    |   b    |   c    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      2 | 3      | 2      | (null) |
|      3 | 5      | 3      | 1      |
|      4 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      5 | 23     | 2      | 2      |
|      6 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+`


What i would like to get, is all records from period 2 to period 5, first occurance of values in measure "a" denotes start of range, last occurance - end of range. 

This works - but i need this to be dynamically calculated during runtime by mdx:

`select non empty {[Measures].[a], [Measures].[b], [Measures].[c]} on columns, 
{[Period].[Period].&[2] :[Period].[Period].&[5]} on rows 
from MyCube`

desired output: 
`+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Period |   a    |   b    |   c    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      2 | 3      | 2      | (null) |
|      3 | 5      | 3      | 1      |
|      4 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      5 | 23     | 2      | 2      |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+`

I tried looking for first/last values but just couldn't compose them into the query properly. Anyone has this issue before ? This should be pretty common seeing as I want to get a continuous financial report without skipping months where nothing is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try playing with `NonEmpty` / `Tail` function in a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH 
SET [First] AS
  {HEAD(NONEMPTY([Period].[Period].MEMBERS, [Measures].[a]))}
SET [Last] AS
  {TAIL(NONEMPTY([Period].[Period].MEMBERS, [Measures].[a]))}
SELECT
  {
   [Measures].[a]
 , [Measures].[b]
 , [Measures].[c]
  } on columns, 
   [First].ITEM(0).ITEM(0) 
  :[Last].ITEM(0).ITEM(0)  on rows 
FROM MyCube;
```

---

to debug a custom set, to see what members it is returning you can do something like this:

```
WITH 
SET [First] AS
  {HEAD(NONEMPTY([Period].[Period].MEMBERS, [Measures].[a]))}
SELECT
  {
   [Measures].[a]
 , [Measures].[b]
 , [Measures].[c]
  } on columns, 
   [First]  on rows 
FROM MyCube;
```

---

I think reading your comment about Children means that this is also an alternative - to add an extra `[Period]`:

```
WITH 
SET [First] AS
  {HEAD(NONEMPTY([Period].[Period].[Period].MEMBERS
     , [Measures].[a]))}
SET [Last] AS
  {TAIL(NONEMPTY([Period].[Period].[Period].MEMBERS
     , [Measures].[a]))}
SELECT
  {
   [Measures].[a]
 , [Measures].[b]
 , [Measures].[c]
  } on columns, 
   [First].ITEM(0).ITEM(0) 
  :[Last].ITEM(0).ITEM(0)  on rows 
FROM MyCube;
```

Comment: thanks, it's coming back empty. Trying to debug it now, not sure why it's not working. How can i output the set to see what's in it ?

Comment: works. Children instead of allmembers ( misspelling there ) - this way first doesn't pick up ALL member. Thanks a bunch, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Fd-ski no worries - glad you found a solution: I added a bit more to the answer re. debugging and also the general alternative to children